# GStreamer recording a stream to a wav file with wrong duration

Tags: gstreamer, wav

I'm recording a wav file using GStreamer receiving G711 flow through a UDP port.
Any wav player can play the file, but shows a wrong duration and cannot fast forward.
I believe that GStreamer writes the header at the beginning with empty data.

This pipeline can reproduce the issue:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=3000 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio, payload=0,clock-rate=(int)8000" ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtppcmudepay ! mulawdec ! wavenc !  filesink append=true location=c:/recordings/audio-zz.wav
```

Florian Zwoch suggested to use -e and the file will be closed properly.
  Indeed it works perfectly.

I'm using this pipeline inside a Java program with the gst1-java-core library.
  Seems that I'm missing something closing the pipeline.
  My program has the same behaviour as gst-launch without -e parameter.

Before stopping the pipeline I send an EOS Event.

pipeline.sendEvent(new EOSEvent());

How can I fix it?

The append parameter of filesink element does not allow rewriting the header.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you stop the pipeline? If you interrupt the pipeline with ctrl-c it may indeed be that the header finalization is skipped. Run your pipeline with the `-e` option so that on ctrl-c your pipeline gets stopped gracefully.

Comment: Hi Florian, Thank you for your answer.

  I'm using this pipeline inside a Java program with the gst1-java-core library.
  Seems that I'm missing something closing the pipeline.
  My program has the same behaviour as gst-launch without -e parameter.

  Before stopping the pipeline I send an EOS Event.

  pipeline.sendEvent(new EOSEvent());

Comment: But do you wait for the EOS to arrive on the bus? Actually you don't need sending EOS from an application. Just properly set your pipeline state from PLAYING to NULL or READY and it should properly finalize your wav header.

Comment: Or maybe you need EOS.. found some old code where I do that too. But you need to wait for this EOS to reach the end of the pipeline and reported on the pipeline's bus before you exit your app or delete the pipeline.